# Is it possible to call a template file inside wysiwyg editor? And how?

Tags: templates, wysiwyg, get-template-part

Is it possible to call a template file, say for example **mycustomtemplate.php** inside the default Wordpress WYSIWYG editor?

I had this content.

My team (This is my content inside the WYSIWYG) then I would like to call a template file. When your inside a template file you would write

```
    <?php get_template_part('includes/page-team-list'); ?>
```

So how could I do this on the WYSIWYG editor? Or I have to use some **PHP plugins** for these php codes to work on WYSIWYG?

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/14/advanced-layout-templates-in-wordpress-content-editor/ please follow the link may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP (unlike HTML) is not meant to be used as content markup language. It is *server–side* language with too much access. It is very challenging to safely and securely treat PHP as part of content.

For basic example — what if one of your authors writes PHP code in a post which amounts to "make me site's administrator"?

While WP plugins implementing this do exist, this is almost never good idea, especially at multi–author site.

The *typical* way of handling more elaborate content in WordPress is via custom fields / meta boxes (/frameworks for both), although it usually falls farther away from WYSIWYG.

Comment: I have resolve my problem, I made a separate template then use custom fields to call the template file page-team-list.